# How would Richard Spencer execute a 'peaceful ethnic cleansing' if he gets elected?

Tags: united-states

Richard Spencer, a prominent leader of the Alt Right wants a ['peaceful ethnic cleansing'](https://mediamatters.org/blog/2016/03/03/white-nationalist-group-headed-by-peaceful-ethn/208996). How would he do that? The way I see it, it can't be done peacefully without killing thousands of people because people won't go out of their homes peacefully. Or does he have a better plan that may work? For example, sending all non-Whites to liberal cities like New York and California and allying with black nationalists and let them create their own state in the black majority areas near the east? What exactly does he intend to do?

Comment: Anyone promoting any form of 'ethnic cleansing' is just a blowhard full of rhetoric. Their intent isn't to execute anything...just spew rhetoric.

Comment: @blip Usually I would refrain from violating Godwin's Law, but in this case it is entirely justified to say: That's exactly what moderate people said about Adolf Hitler.

Comment: @Philipp I wish I could disagree with your point. But I can't. Yikes. :)

Comment: "It can't be done peacefully without killing thousands of people" if you kill people then it's not peaceful. Perhaps you meant to say "It can't be done peacefully *because* without killing thousands of people, they won't leave their homes"?

Comment: @Philipp Wow, that's a 100% precise shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an interview with [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/12/06/politics/richard-spencer-interview-texas-am-speech/) he said this:

> "We have experienced this mass migration of people" into the United States, Spencer said. "Therefore they could go home, you can go home again. ... They came here peacefully. They could leave peacefully."
>   "There are ways -- **whether it's a direct payment, whether it's showing them the beauty of being reconnected with their real culture**, there are ways of what you could call re-immigration."

I agree though that this does not seem like a realistic plan. It is likely propaganda he uses because calling for the forceful expulsion or killing of all people he considers non-white - using a definition which would not include Jews, Hispanics, etc as white - is not politically acceptable.

It is not so much that he is laying out a specific plan, but testing the boundaries of what can be proposed.